# Typescript accusing error when using catch

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I have a problem, I'm trying to use catch to display an error message via API, but Typescript displays the following message:

> Unsafe member access .data on an `any` value.

This would be my code inside catch:

```
.catch((err) => {
  loginError.value = true
  console.log(err.response.data.message)
})
```

This here would be my response inside err:

[image]

Comment: That's because `err` **can be anything** because any code in JS can do `throw null` or `throw "hello, world";` - so you need to handle that in TS. You'll need a type-guard function (`function isMyError( x: unknown ): x is MyError { ... }`) for your `err.response.data.message` case **and** also handle the case when `err: unknown` (fortunately we don't need to use `err: any` anymore).

Answer (score 0):

- Exceptions in JavaScript are untyped, and TypeScript cannot use type-checked `catch` blocks (nor `.catch` promise methods).

  - Indeed, it's perfectly valid to do `throw null;` or `throw "Hello, world";` in JavaScript.
  - ...and TypeScript code *must* correctly handle those situations.

...so you need to handle *all of those cases* in TS. To do this, you'll need a type-guard function, like so:

```js
interface MyError extends Error {
    readonly response: MyResponse;
}

interface MyResponse {
    readonly data: MyData;
}

interface MyData {
    readonly message: string;
}

function isMyError( x: unknown ): x is MyError {
    
    const whatIf = x as MyError;
    return (
        typeof whatIf?.response?.data?.message === 'string'
    );
}
```

Then change your code to use `async/await` with `try/catch` instead of old-style Promise `.then().catch`:

```js
try {
    await yourPromise();

    loginError.value = false;
}
catch( err: unknown ) {

    loginError.value = true;

    if( isMyError( err ) ) {
        console.error( "MyError: %s", err.response.data.message );
    }
    else {
        console.error( "Unexpected error: %o", err );
    }
}
```